My RestController is not being reached. How do i fix it?
I'm trying to build a simple registration web app using reactJS and Spring Boot. However, database(Postgresql) doesnt seem to be receiving anything.
here is my frontend submit code, where REGISTER_URL is just '/register'
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // for the case where button was enabled illegally
        const v1 = USER_REGEX.test(user);
        const v2 = PWD_REGEX.test(pwd);
        if (!v1 || !v2) {
            setErrMsg("Invalid Entry");
            return;
        }
        // use axios to submit user and pwd
        try {
            const response = await axios.post(REGISTER_URL, 
                JSON.stringify({user, pwd}),
                {
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                    withCredentials: true
                });
                console.log(response.data);
                setSuccess(true);
        } catch (err) {
            if (!err?.response) {
                setErrMsg('No server response');
            } else if (err.response?.status === 409) {
                setErrMsg('Username Taken');
            } else {
                setErrMsg('Registration failed')
            }
            // errRef.current.focus();
        }
    }

as for the backend, here is my RestController:
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistrationController.class);

    @Autowired
    private RegistrationRepository registrationRepository;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody Registration user) {

        logger.info("Received username: {}", user.getUsername());
        logger.info("Received password: {}", user.getPassword());
        // Your registration logic here
        Registration registration = new Registration();
        registration.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        registration.setPassword(user.getPassword());

        registrationRepository.save(registration);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("User registered successfully");
    }
}

and here is my entity:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Registration {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Registration() {
    }

    public Registration(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }


}

I have tried logging to see if it even enters my RestController but it doesnt seem to do so.

You've to target the full url of your backend, not just '/register' who targets the frontend.

When using dto class as class that attacted annotation about JPA, serialization and deserialization may not work well.
Therefore, it seems that postgresql is not working well
Create new class that contains necessary field.
Try this
@Getter
@NoargsConstructor
@AllargsConstructor
public class RegistrationDto {

   private String userName;
   private String password;
}

//example service code
@Service
public class RegisterService {

   @Autowired
   private RegisterationRepository repository

   public void execute(RegistrationDto dto) {
      Registration rs = new Registration(dto.getUserName(), dto.getPassword());

      repository.save(rs);
   }
}

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RestController
public class RegistrationController {

    @Autowired
    private RegisterService service;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody RegistrationDto dto) {
        service.execute(dto);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}

Additionaly, i think opening transaction in controller layer is not good.
